# How do I connect an ActionScript 3 client to a Java server?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, java-server

I'm thinking of making a 2D top-down MMO browser game. I want it to be a Flash game because that gives it a much larger target audience, but I also want to have real-time multiplayer action for which the speed of Java would help, and so am I right in saying that an ActionScript 3 client with a Java server would do the trick?

I'm just wondering if a) the above is correct and viable and b) how such a thing could be achieved, or is it no different to connecting a Java client to a Java server? (I'm not familiar with ActionScript 3 right now)

Comment: You can get more answers on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways.
1)  You can call java objects directly using Adobe's [BlazeDS](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/) or 3rd Party [Granite](http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229378) data services.  BlazeDS is deployed as a server or Tomcat servlet/Java EE.  it's job is to marshal your data objects between AS3<->Java Object and call your java class methods.

2) You can call any backend web services or Rest interface using Flex's HTTPService object.

Answer (score 2):

I would use sockets. Flash gives you access to network sockets which you can then send json over, or whatever your preferred format is.